# perl lookbehind bug?

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

```perl
use v5.34;
$_ = "#    name = 'epii1/tagbar-markdown'";
if(/name(?<!#\s{0,20})\s*=\s*'.*'/) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```

I want to match strings which contain `name = '.*'` and are not commented.
For example,   `name = 'tpope/vim-scriptease'` should be matched, and `#    name = 'epii1/tagbar-markdown'` should not. I use a negative zero-width assertion, not positive. I know the right pattern should be `(?<!#\s{0,20})name\s*=\s*'.*'`. I just want to have a try and I think the pattern in the code block is wrong, and the given string would be matched. However, nothing is printed (except the warning about variable length lookbehind), so perl judges it is not matched.
Then I write in javascript:

```js
let text = "#    name = 'epii1/tagbar-markdown'";
let pattern = /name(?<!#\s{0,20})\s*=\s*'.*'/;
let result = pattern.test(text);
console.log(result);
```

`result` gives `true`.
So is this a bug of perl?

Comment: Why are you using a lookbehind in Perl when you actually want to match the whitespace? I would just use `^\s*name\s*=\s*'[^']*';$` if you just want to match one line which is not commented.

Comment: I want to learn about lookaround.

Comment: @TLP lookbehind can be variable length, not more than 255. It is an experimental feature. `which will never happen`, I agree and that is the problem. It should be matched. But perl does not think so. I use a negative zero-width assertion, not positive.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. You think that adding the quantifier `{0,20}` makes the negative lookbehind fail when it should match. What I have noticed is that it fails for 20, but succeeds for values lower than 8, which is where `name` match ends in the string. So it is short circuiting the match for string length. Try `{0,6}` instead.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should try and add some examples of what you mean. The javascript code example doesn't make any sense at all, as it doesn't even contain a lookbehind. Its not the same regex.

Comment: You could take a look at the output of `-mre=debug` and see if it makes sense to you. I started writing up an answer, but that kinda threw me off, and someone who knows that stuff better should explain it.

Comment: @TLP You are right, I gave a wrong javascript code example and I should fix that. Thanks.

Comment: @Tokubara This might be a javascript question more than a Perl question. Perl is fairly solid when it comes to text processing and regex, if there is a bug, its more likely to be a javascript bug.

Comment: Re "*so perl judges it is not matched.*", That is a bug. Not the first time I've heard of bugs in the experimental variable-length look-behind.